# Prove that permutation of a sequence does not affect convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

> Given a sequence $\{y_k\}$ is obtained by permuting the sequence $\{x_n\}$ and:
>   $$
> \{\forall n\in \mathbb N\ \exists k_n \in \mathbb N:x_n = y_{k_n}, n_1 \ne n_2 \implies k_{n_1} \ne k_{n_2}\}
> $$
>   and:
>   $$
> \{\forall k\in \mathbb N\ \exists n_k \in \mathbb N:y_k = x_{n_k}, k_1 \ne k_2 \implies n_{k_1} \ne n_{k_2}\}
> $$
>   Prove that:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = a \implies \lim_{k\to \infty}y_k=a
> $$

I've been thinking of the following. Let there exist a bijection $P:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ which converts $k$ to $n_k$. So basically we have that if $x_n$ is convergent to some $a$ then:

$$
|x_n - a| < \varepsilon
$$

Thus :
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists N \in \mathbb N:n \ge N \implies |x_n - a| < \varepsilon
$$

This is only valid after some $N$. The only terms violating that condition are $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_N$. My guess was that we could take $\max\{P(n)\}$ and that would imply that $|y_{P(n)} - a| < \varepsilon$, so:
$$
\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \exists\ M = \max\{n: 1 \le P(n) \le N\}: n>M \implies |y_n-a| < \varepsilon
$$

I decided to test this idea graphically and [here is what I got](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a7467wpygx). 
$$
x_n = \frac{10}{n}
$$

So from the graph for $\varepsilon = 4$ it follows that for $N \ge 3 $ all terms of $x_n$ are satisfying the condition of convergence. Now if we take the maximum value for $P(n)$ where $n \le 3$ we get $16$. But after $y_{16}$ there exists a value $y_{19}$ which falls out of the neighborhood of $0$.

Where did I get it wrong and how to prove the statement in the problem section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $\{a\}$ converges then for any $\epsilon > 0$  there is an $N>0$ such than $n>N \implies |a_n - a| < \epsilon$

This means that there are only finitely many $a_n$ such that $|a_n - a| > \epsilon$

When we permute $\{a\}$ to construct $\{b\}$ then there are only finitely many $b_m$ such that $|b_m - a| > \epsilon$

And we can choose $M$ such that $M$ is greater than the largest index associated with $|b_m - a| < \epsilon$

and $m>M \implies |b_m - a| < \epsilon$

What is the problem with your graph?  In your graph, you have only plotted finitely many members of the sequence.