# If a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers is modified by changing a finite number of terms, then the result is an equivalent Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

I want to prove that if a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers is modified by changing a finite number of terms, then the result is an equivalent Cauchy sequence. I tried the problem but I'm not sure if what I'm saying is enough. Here it is:

Proof:

Let $\{y_n\}$ be the sequence obtained by modifying a finite number of terms in $\{x_n\}$. Since there are finitely many modified terms, they all must lie between the first term and the last modified term. Suppose a term $\{x_n\}$ is modified if $1 \leq n \leq N'$, where $x_{N'}$ is the last modified term of $\{x_n\}$.

Claim: $\{y_n\}\sim \{x_n\}$

Let $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Q}^+$ and choose $N \geq N' + 1$, which we may do by the archimedean property.

$|y_n-x_n|  = |y_n - x_m + x_m - x_n| \leq |y_n - x_m| + |x_m-x_n|$, or

$|y_n-x_n| \leq |y_n - x_m| + |x_n-x_m|$.

Now, since $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy and $y_n = x_n$ if $n \geq N' + 1$, it follows that:

$|y_n-x_n| \leq |x_n-x_m| + |x_n-x_m| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$.

Therefore $\{y_n-x_n\}$ converges to zero and $\{y_n\}\sim \{x_n\}$.

Is this correct? Do I still need to show that $\{y_n\}$ is Cauchy?

Comment: Look at [Prove that permutation of a sequence does not affect convergence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019027/prove-that-permutation-of-a-sequence-does-not-affect-convergence).

Comment: So what I did is wrong?

Comment: it looks fine, but if it were homework I would add a sentence to make clear that the reasoning, when $y_n$ is Cauchy, is the same. Also, I see no need for mentioning the Archimedean property.